# What does this Lambda function mean?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

```
def largestNumber(self, num):
    num = [str(x) for x in num]
    num.sort(cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(y+x, x+y))
    return ''.join(num).lstrip('0') or '0'
```

What I would like to know is what is exactly is happening in the num.sort line where the lambda function takes in an x and y and does this cmp() function. This is the specific question that the code is being used for if anyone wants to see this as well https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/#/description

Comment: note that this `cmp` stuff is python 2 only.

Comment: I mean it is pretty clear that it is adding x and y together in different order. (and I am assuming the order matters here since num is full of strings). But what is exactly happening in the sort? For instance if I had num = ['300', '98', '9'] does it compare '998' with '989', '9300' .... and so on?

Comment: it tries to sort according to lexicographic order of numbers combined together. If you ask me that's stupid because it's not converting back to integer.

Comment: Oh I see this makes more sense. Thanks! Yeah the reason why it doesn't do this is because sometimes the number can get to big so the question asked for it keep it as a string

Comment: you know that python can handle huge ints, there's no limit like C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use [Visualize python](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) with the following code:

```
class Solution:
    def largestNumber(self, num):
        num = [str(x) for x in num]
        num.sort(cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(y+x, x+y))
        return ''.join(num).lstrip('0') or '0'

print Solution().largestNumber([4,6,2,7,8,2,4,10])
```

To get the concept clear,

```
num = [str(x) for x in num]
```

This takes every element of list `num` as x and converts it to a string and the result list is stored as `num`

```
num.sort(cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(y+x, x+y))
```

[**cmp**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp):

> cmp(x, y)¶
>       Compare the two objects x and y and return an integer according to the outcome. The return value is negative if x < y, zero if x == y and
>   strictly positive if x > y.

[**Lambda Expression**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

> Small anonymous functions can be created with the lambda keyword. This
>   function returns the sum of its two arguments: lambda a, b: a+b.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the lambda function does exactly the comparisons you suggest: "998" to "989", etc.  This way, the list items are sorted into lexicographic order, largest first.  You have to worry about the concatenated combinations to get the proper order for largest numbers: '9' vs '98' is a typical example of why you need concatenation, as you want "998" in the result.